# Declaring an object within (vs. outside) a while loop

Tags: python-2.7

Given the python 2.7 code below:

```
# faultReportObj = {}
flatDataObj    = []
while row:
    faultReportObj = {}
    faultReportObj['MessageTime']             = row['MessageTime']
    faultReportObj['Event']                   = row['Event']
    faultReportObj['Subsystem']               = row['Subsystem']
    faultReportObj['UnifiedFaultCode']        = row['UnifiedFaultCode']
    faultReportObj['FaultDescription']        = row['FaultDescription']
    faultReportObj['FaultDetails']            = row['FaultDetails']
    faultReportObj['FirstOccurrenceDateTime'] = row['FirstOccurrenceDateTime']
    faultReportObj['LastOccurrenceDateTime']  = row['LastOccurrenceDateTime']
    faultReportObj['OccurrenceCount']         = row['OccurrenceCount']
    print "current row:"
    pp.pprint(faultReportObj)
    flatDataObj.append(faultReportObj)
    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()

pp.pprint(flatDataObj)
```

If I declare `faultReportObj` *outside* the while loop, I get (say) 96 entries in `flatDataObj` that are all identical to the very last row returned by the query. Note that the `pprint` statement within the while loop prints the expected (varying) results.

If, as above, I declare `faultReportObj` *inside* the loop, flatDataObj is loaded correctly.

Why???? Why is the very last row returned being propagated throughout the entire list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `list.append` inserting a *reference* to `faultReportObj` and not copying the value of the `dict`.

Another way of looking at it:

If you define `faultReportObj` before the loop, the following occurs:

1. Create a new dict.
2. Populate it.
3. Append a reference to the dict into the list.
4. Change the dict's content.
5. Append another reference to the same dict.
6. etc.

Here's a short piece of code that exemplifies this property:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> l = []
>>> l.append(d)
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> l
[{1: 2}]
```

What you want is for step one (Create a new dict) to happen in every iteration of the loop, so that you append a different dict every time.

Comment: Wow. Subtle. Thanks. I went back through my code base this morning and it looks like this is the first time I tried to declare a dict outside the loop in this way. Not sure how I missed it!